# jquery - convert string to object, url got stripped

Tags: jquery

I am converting an string to a object, but it is stripping the link,
please fix my code so that it cannot strip url/link.
currently it is stripping this

`url("http://localhost/xyz.jpg")` to `url("http`

```
        var style = 'background-image:url("http://localhost/xyz.jpg");
                    font-size: 20px;font-weight: 300;padding: 20px 10px;';
        if (typeof style != 'undefined'){
            var att = style.slice(0,-1).split(';');
            var obj = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < att.length; i++) {
                var parts = att[i].split(':');
                obj[parts[0]] = parts[1].substring(1);
            }
            console.log( obj);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `var parts = att[i].split(':');` you are splitting by `:` and getting only `url("http` which is exactly between two `:`

Comment: Oh yes... I did not notice that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you get only two chunks after `split()`:

Instead of this:

```
var parts = att[i].split(':');
```

Do this:

```
var parts = att[i].split(':');
parts = [parts.shift(), parts.join(':')];
```

Example:

```
> parts = 'background-image:url("http://localhost/xyz.jpg");'.split(':')
["background-image", "url("http", "//localhost/xyz.jpg");"]
> parts = [parts.shift(), parts.join(':')]
["background-image", "url("http://localhost/xyz.jpg");"]
```

Comment: Please note: there is a blank space after `:` so I am using this `.substring(1)`

Comment: The rest of the code can remain the same (except that you do not need to _always_ strip the first character). Why not use `str.trim()` (new browsers) or `str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')` (old browsers) instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the

```
var parts = att[i].split(':');
```

line with

```
var parts = att[i].split(/:(?!\/)/);
```

to only split at `:`s that are not followed by a `/` (using negative lookahead).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var style = 'background-image:url("http://localhost/xyz.jpg"); font-size: 20px;font-weight: 300;padding: 20px 10px;';
if (typeof style != 'undefined'){
    var att = style.split(';');
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < att.length; i++) {
        if(att[i]){
            var parts = att[i].match(/^\s?([a-z-]+):(.*)/);
            obj[parts[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '')] = parts[2].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
        }
    }
    console.log( JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PpNdG/)